# Нормы, установленные на настоящее время или нормы, установленные на текущий период

Tags: стилистика

Как лучше сказать:

нормы, установленные на настоящее время

или

нормы, установленные на текущий период

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: нормы, установленные на текущий период.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Этот вариант соответствует общепринятой терминологии, например:

Нормы разрабатываются обычно на краткосрочный, заранее установленный период их применения, в заданных производственных условиях с учетом различных производственно-хозяйственных факторов. Нормы подлежат пересмотру в соответствии с изменением нормообразующих факторов http://www.aup.ru/books/m235/2_1.htm

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать: Установленные на данный период нормы; Действующие в настоящий момент нормы; Нормы, установленные на текущий момент/ период/в(на)данный момент/в настоящий момент.

Вариант ***"На настоящее время" стилистически не безупречен.***